# iam getting "An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module './internal/Observable'" this error not sure what dependence i have to install

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript-typings

iam getting "An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module './internal/Observable'" this error not sure what dependence i have to install

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module './internal/Observable'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\798875\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\office\reposal-2\reposal\sell-frontend\soln\node_modules\@angular-builders\custom-webpack\node_modules\rxjs\index.js
- C:\Users\798875\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\office\reposal-2\reposal\sell-frontend\soln\node_modules\@angular-builders\custom-webpack\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js
- C:\Users\798875\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\office\reposal-2\reposal\sell-frontend\soln\node_modules\@angular-builders\custom-webpack\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\index.js
- C:\Users\798875\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\office\reposal-2\reposal\sell-frontend\soln\node_modules\@angular-builders\custom-webpack\dist\dev-server\index.js
- C:\Users\798875\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\office\reposal-2\reposal\sell-frontend\soln\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Users\798875\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\office\reposal-2\reposal\sell-frontend\soln\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\798875\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\office\reposal-2\reposal\sell-frontend\soln\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\Users\798875\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\office\reposal-2\reposal\sell-frontend\soln\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- C:\Users\798875\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\office\reposal-2\reposal\sell-frontend\soln\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Users\798875\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\office\reposal-2\reposal\sell-frontend\soln\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Users\798875\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\office\reposal-2\reposal\sell-frontend\soln\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Users\798875\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\office\reposal-2\reposal\sell-frontend\soln\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\798875\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\office\reposal-2\reposal\sell-frontend\soln\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\798875\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\798875\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
See "C:\Users\798875\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-n59zVd\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

this is my package.json file .. not sure what is wrong in this?
npm install doesn't seem to solve the problem.
trying different things from half a day.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "^11.0.5",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.1.1",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^8.0.0-beta.4",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^8.0.0-beta.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.3.0",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.2.4",
    "angulartics2": "^8.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "chromium": "^3.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "document-register-element": "^1.14.3",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jscat": "0.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-moment": "^3.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-observable": "0.0.7",
    "single-spa": "^5.8.3",
    "single-spa-angular": "^4.9.1",
    "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "util": "^0.12.1",
    "util.js": "0.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.0.5",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.7.5",
    "codelyzer": "~5.1.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-footer": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-header": "^2.0.9",
    "gulp-json-modify": "^1.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "puppeteer": "^1.20.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~5.20.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.5"
  }
}
```

I am getting the above error not sure what dependencies to install?

Comment: Maybe try installing Observable?

Comment: Where are you importing './internal/Observable' ?

Comment: Please provide error messages as text, not as links to images of text.

Comment: The same error shows up, ,

Comment: Please show the package.json for the project you are trying to build.

Comment: i have not imported it anywhere

Comment: Hi @Sanjanak, how have you solved it?

Answer (score 3):

It's a dependency error on Observable, so you can try to install the rxjs:

`npm install rxjs`

If the error persist, try to delete the `node_modules` and run npm install again.

Another possible problem for that is the white spaces on the path.

Comment: i tried npm install rxjs , no changes in the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try
npm install rxjs
and then ng serve

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  The solution that worked for me was using `npm ci`.  The ci ensures you are getting a clean install of your dependencies.  It removes the `node_modules` if present.
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-ci

Running the command resolved my problem.